# How to use the Edit/add new keyboard shortcuts in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am in the `Edit Command mode Shortcuts` dialog and things *seem* reasonable ..

[image]

But the actual *behavior* is a different story

- When using the `Option` modifier (plus a non-modifier key) it just ends up printing a high-ascii character value in the `add shortcut` area .. and then when I refresh the page it has gone away.
- I can not get `Command` modifier (plus a non-modifier key) to work at all. It is jus ignored.
- The `Control` modifier (plus any key) is completely ignored.

So there is a basic usability misunderstanding here. Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I added 'Ctrl-Q' as a shortcut to restart kernel and run all the cells. You can see the picture below. It is working fine. In the 'Ctrl-Q', 'Q' was just lowercase and it ran successfully.

[image: shortcut's snippet]

Comment: which platform / which browser?  control is completely inoperative in that dialog for me on `macos`/`chrome`

Comment: @javadba: I am using it on windows 10 with chrome browser. After you type `Ctrl-Q` in the `add shortcut` box, press enter and you should see as I had shown in the image.

Comment: ya that's what i'm doing but nothing even gets added to the shortcut box. It's broken in my configuration.

Comment: @javadba You can stop the kernel and restart it again and try. Also, what happens after you type `Ctrl-Q` and click on `+` button?

Comment: i have stopped/restarted kernel several times.  Also tried the + button a few times.

Comment: what is the notebook version you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194465/discussion-between-javadba-and-vishal).